# SignalR and ASP.NET core page not loading

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to set up signalR so that I can send data from my server to javascript to render some graphs.

I added the required items to Startup.cs (removed all the irrelevant things):

```
using MyProject.Hubs

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddSignalR();    
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
         routes.MapHub<GraphHub>("/test");
    });

    app.UseMvc();

}
```

In Hubs.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject.Hubs
{
     public class GraphHub : Hub
     {
        public async Task SendData(int[] data)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("sendGraphData", data);
        }
     }
 }
```

However in my Index.cshtml.cs

```
public IndexModel(MyProject context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{

   IList<Cats> cat = await _context.Ticket.Where(x => x.Color = "Black").ToListAsync();


   int[] TestData = new int[] {65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40};

   var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:44307/test").Build();

   await hubConnection.StartAsync();

   await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendData", TestData);

   await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();      
}
```

Currently the page just gives me a blank screen on `await hubConnection.StartAsync();` and I am not sure how to debug it. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe `.WithUrl()` must be something different

Comment: I tried a different value and it gives me the error 'url format cannot be detected'. I tried a different port and I get an error that the server refused the connection.

Comment: I release it might want a unique route as defined in startup, so I changed 'routes.MapHub<GraphHub>("/test");' and '.WithUrl("http://localhost:44307/test")'. Same issue though.

Comment: Not related to Signalr, but I'm pretty sure that `Where(x => x.Color = "Black")` does not compile. Also the next line `ToListAsync()` most likely needs a `.` in front of it.

Comment: Sorry, the real code is really long so I shorted it. I left if for ages and I now get the error 'SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of a thread exit or application request'. at line await hubConnection.StartAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted my IDE - All fixed now ≧☉_☉≦